# Android Espresso: longClick() does not work and behave like click()

Tags: android, mobile, android-testing, android-espresso

Does anyone saw this problem when you try to LongClick With Android Espresso

Comment: for me it turned out to be that the developers have manipulated the the wait time between these two clicks and espresso expects to see default time between the two clicks to operates. Check if they are using the default time to click or adding more or less time. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html#onDoubleTap(android.view.MotionEvent)